# How do i change/update validation of question (item) in google form with apps scripts

Tags: forms, validation, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have already try to update text validation for my class with google apps scripts but it say "textItem.setValidation is not a function". Please help me

```
function setPass() {
var form = FormApp.openById('Google Form ID');
var textItem = form.getItemById(Question ID);
var textValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
.requireNumberEqualTo(22111)
.build();
textItem.setValidation(textValidation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close to update the question, you only need to add the method [`.asTextItem()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#astextitem) after getting the item by id. The final code should look like this:

```
function setPass() {
var form = FormApp.openById('Google Form ID');
var textItem = form.getItemById(Question ID).asTextItem();
var textValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
.requireNumberEqualTo(22111)
.build();
textItem.setValidation(textValidation)
```

Don't hesitate to ask me any question if you need further help.

Comment: Tks you @Jacques-Guzel Heron a lot, you save my life.