# How can we make a password unique in google form using google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, unique, google-forms

The following script creates a form which will only accept passwords that are only stored in the google sheet(A1 to A250).

Is there a way where the form will not accept more than one response using the same password that's stored in the google sheet. For example if I fill the form from two different email IDs then it shouldn't accept it twice. Once the password is entered then nobody else gets to use it again.

```
function validatePassword() {
  // Create new custom form
  var form = FormApp.create('new');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('');
 
  var passwords = ss.getSheetByName('xyz').getRange('A1:A250').getValues();
  // Ex passwords: asd, 123, asd123
  const conditions = passwords.map(element => `${element}`).join('|')
  // Create first question to check the password, it must be required so that the user does not have access to the rest
  // of the form if failed to log in
  var item = form.addTextItem().setRequired(true);
  //item.setTitle('TEST TITLE');
  // Create valid ation for this question matching the password that we got from the sheet
  var textValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
    .setHelpText('You must enter the right ID code')
    .requireTextMatchesPattern(conditions)
    .build();
  item.setValidation(textValidation);
}
```

Comment: A Google Form has the built in capability to restrict the user to only one response, but it requires that the user is logged in with a Google account.  That setting is under the General settings.  If the user is entering a password as an answer to a question on the Form, then what you want to do is possible, with the caveat that they could submit the Form an infinite number of times, but it just wouldn't ever be saved again in the Sheet.  You'll need to store data about the password and whether the Form was already submitted.

Comment: Can we check the passwords entered in the response sheet with the ones the user is trying to enter. If there is a match then it shouldn't allow the user to do so.

Comment: There are lots of possibilities.  I what you want is the Google Form to prevent the Form from being submitted, then there is only one way to do that, and that is through a Form setting, and the user must be signed in.   If the Sheet is linked to the Form through the built-in capability, then you can't stop the data from being saved to the Sheet.  What you probably want is to use an On Form Submit trigger in the Sheet, and first get the answers from the event object.

Comment: Thank you Alan. Do you have the syntax for this by any chance?

Comment: You need JavaScript code that is specific to your situation.  The first thing that you need to do, is learn about an On Form Submit trigger for Sheets.  Read the documentation at: [Events - Sheets - Form Submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)  You need to get the values.  But there are many other steps in the process.  Start with setting up the On Submit trigger, and getting the values.

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> Once the password is entered then nobody else gets to use it again.

Use an installable on form submit trigger to remove the password that should not be used again from the respective text data validation.

Related

- [remove selected items from google form dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19270325/1595451)
- [How do i change/update validation of question (item) in google form with apps scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61885784/1595451)